# Chat Boubbles WindowsForms c#

Tags: c#, chat

I receive an error using the code in the following question:
[Control snapping on resize in C# scrollable container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30764357/control-snapping-on-resize-in-c-sharp-scrollable-container)
The Error is from this part:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++)
{
    messageControl1.Add(x.ToString("00") + ": Testing testing testing ...",
      MessageControl.BubblePositionEnum.Right);

    messageControl1.Add(x.ToString("00") + ": Testing with variable length strings.  This one is longer!", 
      MessageControl.BubblePositionEnum.Right);

    messageControl1.Add(x.ToString("00") + ": Testing is fun.", 
      MessageControl.BubblePositionEnum.Left);
}
```

It underlines "**Add**".

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: It underlines "Add" after "messageControl1" and tels there is no such action for it. :-(

Comment: What is the type of messageControl1? Is it supposed to have a member named "Add", taking a string and a BubblePositionEnum? What is the expected behavior?

Comment: Due to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30764357/control-snapping-on-resize-in-c-sharp-scrollable-container it is FlowLayoutPanel.

Comment: Looking on the code, this action is to add message bubble to the screen.

Comment: In the code you linked there is an Add function implemented. Check if you also copied that function